# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier seems to call viewdidload

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, instantiation, viewdidload

I am trying to push a ViewController programmatically into a navigation controller, And I'm using my storyboard to create it.

here is my code :

```
+ (void) pushViewController:(NSString *) identifier ForItems:(NSMutableArray *) items sender:(UIViewController *) sender {
    GenericViewController *viewController = (GenericViewController *)[sender.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    viewController.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewController.items removeAllObjects];
    [viewController.items addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    [viewController.items[0] addObjectsFromArray:items];

    [sender.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

In `GenericViewController viewDidLoad` I'm using my `items`. Thanks to some break points I've seen that `GenericViewController viewDidLoad` juste after the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` with an `items` equal to nil.

I thought that `MyViewController viewDidLoad` is called during the `pushViewController` method.

Any idea why `viewDidLoad` is called during `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` ?

**---Update :---**

Here my `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    for (MyItem *currentItem in self.items[0]) {
        [Do Something]
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];


    [...]
}
```

`self.items` is nil. so nothing is done.

Comment: put the complete code please..what is myItem and the viewDidLoad method..the problem is not this..cause when you initiate an object, it is alive.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Show the whole method where you use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:. The method, instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, will not cause viewDidLoad to be called, so something else is going on.

Comment: thank you @rdelmar I am pretty sure `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` do not call `viewDidLoad`. I update my code, I'm using a static manager to instanciate and push my new viewController

Comment: I still don't see anything in your posted code that would cause viewDidLoad to be called before you do the push. Do you have any segues setup to GenericViewController? Is GenericViewController a stand alone controller (not embedded in anything)?

Answer (score 8):

To anyone that might still have the same problem.

I had a similar situation and solved it by just calling loadViewIfNeeded().

```
let sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadingView") as! LoadingViewController
controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

I could then access everything inside the view.

Comment: As documentation says, loadView() should never be called directly.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[vc loadViewIfNeeded]` in Objective-C or `vc.loadViewIfNeeded()` in Swift.

[apple: loadViewIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621446-loadviewifneeded)

Answer (score 1):

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad

`viewDidLoad` is called when the controller's view is loaded into memory.

`viewWillAppear` Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy. I think this is when `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];` is called.

`viewDidAppear` Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy. This is when `MyViewController` is added into `navigationController`.

Comment: it make sense, but so SO questions indicate that it is a good way to pass properties to a view controller. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9666389/1436861, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12709167/1436861)

Answer (score 0):

As voyage11 mentioned, viewDidLoad is called when the controller's view is loaded into memory, although someone has pointed out that this does not necessarily occur during the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method.

Following your example code, I'd put the loop in the viewWillAppear method:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  // good practice to call the super
    for (MyItem *currentItem in self.items[0]) {
        [Do Something]
    }
}
```

Comment: You initial statement is incorrect -- viewDidLoad will not be called just by instantiating a view controller.

Comment: Good point.  I've updated my answer to remove that implication.